# OpenCV initialisation issue on Android

Tags: android, opencv

I use OpenCV on Android and i don't understand why i can't instantiate a simple `Mat`. I think I don't do right implementation of OpenCV with the BaseLoaderCallback.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String TAG = "Main activity";

private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
       switch (status) {
           case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
           {
          Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");             
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           //Mat image = new Mat(); // <--- problem here
           } break;
           default:
           {
          super.onManagerConnected(status);
           } break;
       }
    }
};

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mOpenCVCallBack);
    }
```

My LogCat is only a FatalSignal 11 (SIGSEV).

**EDIT :** After many modifications, this is now works and i don't know why but thanks.

Comment: Try making the `Mat` variable global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

Mat m;
     private static final String    TAG                 = "OCVSample::Activity";

```
  private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
@Override
public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
    switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
            m=new Mat();
        } break;
        default:
        {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        } break;
    }
}
};
```

OpenCV functions such as `Mat` have to be invoked in either a `thread` or `AsyncTask` or from within an OpenCV function.